# Hash Tables- Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, hashtable

Not sure why I'm getting a segmentation fault here. I'm trying to create a hash table that would have collisions and the data should be string. So I'm using a char array for the data. 
Need to detect collisions at the end.

```
#define SIZE 20    
struct DataItem
{
    char data[50];
    int key;
};

struct DataItem* hashArray[SIZE];
struct DataItem* dummyItem;
struct DataItem* item;

int hashCode(int key)
{
    return key % SIZE;
}
void insert(int key, char data[50])
{

    struct DataItem *item = (struct DataItem*) malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));
    strcpy(item->data, data);
    item->key = key;

//get the hash 
    int hashIndex = hashCode(key);

//move in array until an empty or deleted cell
    while (hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL && hashArray[hashIndex]->key != -1)
    {
        //go to next cell
        ++hashIndex;

        //wrap around the table
        hashIndex %= SIZE;
    }

    hashArray[hashIndex] = item;
}

struct DataItem* delete(struct DataItem* item)
{
    int key = item->key;

    //get the hash 
    int hashIndex = hashCode(key);

    //move in array until an empty
    while (hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL)
    {

        if (hashArray[hashIndex]->key == key)
        {
            struct DataItem* temp = hashArray[hashIndex];

            //assign a dummy item at deleted position
            hashArray[hashIndex] = dummyItem;
            return temp;
        }

        //go to next cell
        ++hashIndex;

        //wrap around the table
        hashIndex %= SIZE;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int detect_collisions()
{
    int i = 0;
    int collision = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (hashArray[i] != NULL)
        {
            if (hashArray[i]->key == hashArray[i + 1]->key)
                ;
            collision++;
        }

    }
    return collision;
}

void display()
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (hashArray[i] != NULL)
        {
            printf("Phli dafa: %d\n", i);
            printf(" (%d,%s)", hashArray[i]->key, hashArray[i]->data);
        }
        else
            printf(" ~~ ");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    dummyItem = (struct DataItem*) malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));
    strcpy(dummyItem->data, NULL);
    dummyItem->key = -1;

    insert(1, "check");
    display();
    delete(item);
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(dummyItem->data, NULL);` -------> `boooooom!` or better `KABOOOOOOM!`

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem here:

```
strcpy(dummyItem->data,NULL);
```

as `strcpy` will dereference a NULL pointer.

To put in an empty string use:

```
strcpy(dummyItem->data, "");
```

Your second problem is:

```
delete(item);
```

`item` is NULL at this point. So here:

```
struct DataItem* delete(struct DataItem* item)
{
    int key = item->key;
              ^^^^^^
```

you dereference a NULL pointer.

Maybe your delete function should rather be:

```
struct DataItem* delete(int key)
{
```

The third problem is here (there are actually 3 problems here):

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    if (hashArray[i] != NULL)
    {
        if (hashArray[i]->key == hashArray[i + 1]->key)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                 a) May be NULL
                                 b) Out of range when i == size-1
            ;
           ^^^
           c) Delete this
        collision++;
    }

}
```

My guess is that you want:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE-1; i++)        // Notice
{
    if (hashArray[i] != NULL && hashArray[i + 1] != NULL)   // Notice
    {
        if (hashArray[i]->key == hashArray[i + 1]->key)
        {
            collision++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed part of the problem but I'm still getting a segmentation fault. 
I think something is wrong with my display function

Comment: ...or `struct DataItem *item = (struct DataItem*) malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));` --> `item = malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));`

Comment: The issue is fixed. I'm getting another segmentation fault when trying to find the collisions. 
int detect_collisions()
{
    int i = 0;
 int collision=0;
 int prev=0;
   for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) {
       //prev=hashArray[i]->key;
       if(hashArray[i] != NULL)
         prev=hashArray[i]->key;
         if(hashArray[i]->key==prev)
           collision++;
   }
 return collision;
}

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

```
strcpy(dummyItem->data, NULL);
```

It will try to copy a string pointed by NULL (that is not pointing a string..) to your array. So it invokes [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

What you want (I guess) is

```
memset(dummyItem->data, 0x00, sizeof(dummyItem->data));
```

or

```
dummyItem->data[0] = 0x00;
```

or

```
dummyItem->data[0] = '\0';
```

Take also note that you must always check `malloc` return value: it can fail returning `NULL`

```
dummyItem = malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));
if ( dummyItem != NULL)
{
   // YOUR STUFF
}
```

You have also a ; just after

```
if (hashArray[i]->key == hashArray[i + 1]->key)
```

remove it.

Last thing I can see

```
delete(item);
```

is UB because of item is not initialized because the code in `insert` function uses a local variable, maybe you want change

```
struct DataItem *item = (struct DataItem*) malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));
```

to

```
item = malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));
```

**EDIT 1**

You are also accessing the array out of bounds with

```
if (hashArray[i]->key == hashArray[i + 1]->key)
```

`hashArray[i + 1]` is out of bounds when `i = SIZE-1`
Moreover `hashArray[i + 1]` can be `NULL` or not initialized.

Comment: This fixed part of the problem but I'm still getting a segmentation fault. 
I think something is wrong with my display function

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your code with debugging turned on ( ie -g option with gcc ) and then run it in a debugger it will tell you what lines the seg faults are happen on. There are two places that are causing a seg fault that I can see - the strcpy being passed a NULL and also the call to `delete(item)` where item is still NULL. Presumably because you think you're using the one defined in `insert` rather than the globally defined one.